# Pulp Optimization Error - LPVariable Object Does Not Support Indexing

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I am consistently getting errors when trying to add the constraint located on line 31, model += ([MAHL[i][j] for (i,j) in yearlyhours]) <= 40

I am not sure how to correctly set up this constraint.  I am trying to say that at each index of i and j that the specific value needs to be less than 40 and do it for all i, j pairs.

I am very new to PULP and trying to get a basic model up and running.  Input data is just a bunch of random values that are 365 rows long and 24 columns wide.

```
from pulp import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlrd

model = pulp.LpProblem("Basic Model", pulp.LpMaximize)

YPER = 365
HE = 24

yearlyhours = [(i,j) for i in range(YPER) for j in range(HE)]

xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('IvA.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet5')
df2 = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet3')
df3 = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet2')

MAHL = pulp.LpVariable('MAHL', (YPER, HE), cat='Integer')
MALL = pulp.LpVariable('MALL', cat='Integer')
DAHL = pulp.LpVariable('DAHL', cat='Integer')
DALL = pulp.LpVariable('DALL', cat='Integer')

book = xlrd.open_workbook('IvA.xlsx')
sheet10 = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet10')
sheet11 = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet11')

DAPRICE = [[sheet10.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet10.ncols)] for r in range(sheet10.nrows)]
LOAD = [[sheet11.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet11.ncols)] for r in range(sheet11.nrows)]

#model += (MAHL[i][j] for i in range(YPER) for j in range(HE)) <= 40
model += ([MAHL[i][j] for (i,j) in yearlyhours]) <= 40

model += (pulp.lpSum([DAPRICE[i][j] * LOAD[i][j] for i in range(YPER) for j in range(HE)]))

model.solve()
pulp.LpStatus[model.status]
print("Status:", LpStatus[model.status])

obj = value(model.objective)
print(obj)
```

I am tried a few solutions, one additional is commented out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bs.py", line 31, in <module>
    model += ([MAHL[i][j] for (i,j) in yearlyhours]) <= 40
  File "bs.py", line 31, in <listcomp>
    model += ([MAHL[i][j] for (i,j) in yearlyhours]) <= 40
TypeError: 'LpVariable' object does not support indexing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined `MAHL` as a `pulp.LpVariable`, which (as the error states) does not support indexing since it models an LP Variable.

You may want to define it using `pulp.LpVariable.dicts`.

Example:

```
MAHL = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('MAHL', yearlyhours, cat=pulp.LpInteger)
```

and refer to it as

```
model += pulp.lpSum([MAHL[(i,j)] for (i,j) in yearlyhours]) <= 40
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks for not only answering but helping me learn